# Javascript: Sorting JSON object by lowest price

Tags: javascript, json, sorting

Hi I'm working on a function that is sorting my JSON object by the lowest price.

This is how the structure looks like

```
{
"successful": true,
"products": [
{
  "id": "47",
  "name": "HP LP3065",
  "price": "$119.50",
  "description": "",
  "special": false,
  "rating": 0
},
{
  "id": "43",
  "name": "MacBook",
  "price": "$589.50",
  "description": "",
  "thumb": "data/demo/macbook_1.jpg",
  "special": false,
  "rating": 0
 }
]
}
```

And this is how my current sorting function looks like

```
 data.products.sort(function(a, b){
   if (a.price.substr(1, a.price.length) === b.price.substr(1, b.price.length)) {

     if (a.price.substr(1, a.price.length) > b.price.substr(1, b.price.length)) {
        return b;
     }

     return a;
   }   
 });
```

The current function i have done is not work, so do you guys have any suggestions?

Comment: And your question is...? Do you have an error? Is the code just not working?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Why are you doing funny stuff like this, just lose the $, convert to a float and comp them.

Comment: I recommend you look at underscorejs - it's great for working with JSON objects: http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy

Comment: @Fraccus What does the way in which an object is created have to do with a libraries usability?

Comment: @scragar - I am not sure I understand your question? Did you read that I am implying that Underscore's usability is limited to JSON objects alone? Surely not?

Comment: @Fraccus "it's great for working with JSON objects" What makes a JSON object different to a normal object? They don't appear to display any dissimilar properties or anything. Either underscore is good in general for objects, or it's doing something very strange.

Comment: @scragar - At no point am I comparing objects to arrays. The OP's question contained JSON, hence the specific reference. Is any part of my statement incorrect or misleading?

Answer (score 1):

You need to rewrite a comparator to return a number. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

```
function price(obj) { //convert obj.price to float
    return parseFloat(obj.price.replace(/[^\.\d]/g, ''));
}

data.products.sort(function(a, b){
   return price(a) - price(b);  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the prices as strings, that's why you don't get the result that you expect. You should parse the prices as floating point numbers.

Your `substr` Calls are not right, the length that you specify is one character too much as you are skipping one character. (This however doesn't keep the calls from doing what you expect, as the method accepts values that are out of range.). It should be `a.price.substr(1, a.price.length - 1)`, but you can just skip the second parameter to get all characters to the end of the string: `a.price.substr(1)`.

When comparing numbers, you can just subtract one from the other. That will give the negative/zero/positive result that the `sort` method expects:

```
data.products.sort(function(a, b){
  return parseFloat(a.price.substr(1)) - parseFloat(b.price.substr(1));
});
```